# Method returning as interface

Tags: java

Consider this example:

I have 3 interfaces: A, B, C, with methods a(), b(), c(); extending a base interface Intf;

I have a enum with options MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C;

I have a class extending this 3 interfaces: X implements A, B, C;

There is a way to implement a method in X like this;

```
public <T extends Intf> T getType (MyEnum enum)
```

and the result is the interface A, B or C, that is, accessing only method a(), b() or c()?

EDIT: I want to use it on a builder with fluent api:

```
X var = X.getType(MyEnum.A).a("value").build();
```

or

```
X var = X.getType(MyEnum.B).b("value").build();
```

but never

```
X var = X.getType(MyEnum.A).b("value").build(); //ERROR
```

Comment: I am not sure about the first requirement: As it stands I am assuming that the baseInterface Intf has the 3 methods a(), b() and c(). But as I keep reading I am not sure whether this is the case.

Comment: Please don't *explain* code, show it. And please show how you would want to use / call the method `getType(...)`.

Comment: Exactly. Code is best explained by minimal code examples!

Comment: I guess the OP wants `getType(MyEnum.A)` to return an instance of `A`, `getType(MyEnum.B)` to return an instance of `B` etc. - i.e. to express this in a method signature.

Comment: A signature like `public <T extends Intf> T getType (MyEnum enum)` makes no sense. That signature says “whatever the caller wishes, I’ll return it”. You could even say `String s = X.getType(…)`. Surely, `String` doesn’t implement `Intf`, but there *could* be a type extending `String` and implementing `Intf` and your method will have a hard time fulfilling that promise and returning an instance of such a type, especially as `String` is `final`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you want compile-time safety for

```
public <T extends Intf> T getType (MyEnum enum)
```

to return `A` for `MyEnum.A`, `B` for `MyEnum.B` etc.

You can achieve this compile-time safety if you make `MyEnum` class generic. This does now work with normal enums, but it works with old-fashioned "typesafe enum" pattern.

Assume we have three interfaces `AA`, `BB` , `CC` extending the base interface `II`:

```
public interface AA extends II { void a(); }
public interface BB extends II { void b(); }
public interface CC extends II { void c(); }
```

Now the class `TT` implements all of these interfaces:

```
public class TT implements AA, BB, CC {

    @Override
    public void a() { ... }

    @Override
    public void b() { ... }

    @Override
    public void c() { ... }

}
```

Now let `EE` be our generic pseudo-enum class, parameterized with some subtype of `II`:

```
public class EE<XX extends II> {

    public static final EE<AA> A = new EE<AA>();
    public static final EE<BB> B = new EE<BB>();
    public static final EE<CC> C = new EE<CC>();

}
```

With these definitions the `getType` method can be declared as follows:

```
public <XX extends II> XX getType(EE<XX> enumVal)
```

This method may only return the type the type which parameterized the `enumVal`. Meaning

```
AA type = tt.getType(EE.A);
```

is valid but

```
BB type = tt.getType(EE.A);
```

is not.

One of the ways to implement the `getType` method would be delegate "conversion" of the `TT` instance to `AA`, `BB` or `CC` to the corresponding pseudo-enums:

```
public abstract class EE<XX extends II> {

    public static final EE<AA> A = new EE<AA>() {
        @Override
        public <PP extends AA & BB & CC> AA convert(PP instance) {
            return new AA() {
                public void a() {
                    instance.a();
                };
            };
        }
    };
    public static final EE<BB> B = new EE<BB>() {
        @Override
        public <PP extends AA & BB & CC> BB convert(PP instance) {
            return new BB() {
                public void b() {
                    instance.b();
                };
            };
        }
    };
    public static final EE<CC> C = new EE<CC>() {
        @Override
        public <PP extends AA & BB & CC> CC convert(PP instance) {
            return new CC() {
                public void c() {
                    instance.c();
                };
            };
        }
    };

    public abstract <PP extends AA & BB & CC> XX convert(PP instance);
}
```

You can also return `instance` directly, without wrapping in an anonymous inner class. But then the result can be force-casted to the other interfaces thus allowing access to other methods.

Finally, the implementation of `getType` is trivial:

```
public <XX extends II> XX getType(EE<XX> enumVal) {
    return enumVal.convert(this);
}
```

From what I can see, the compiler won't allow

```
BB bb = tt.getType(EE.A);
```

Also

```
BB bb = (BB) tt.getType(EE.A);
bb.b();
```

won't work as in "produces `ClassCastException` in the runtime".

The disadvantages are a pseudo-enum construct and somewhat ugly implementation of `convert`.

Comment: This answer is close to what I need.

Comment: @marciel.deg If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

You could dispatch the enum value, and return a matching instance, as @GhostCat suggested.

You could also **invert the lookup**, so **each enum value provides an appropriate instance** of `Intf`:

**Variant 1**: singleton instance per enum value

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A(new AImpl()),
    B(new BImpl()),
    C(new CImpl());

    private Intf instance;

    MyEnum2(Intf instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public <T extends Intf> T getType() {
        return (T) instance;
    }
}
```

**Variant 2**: factory, creating new instances:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A(AImpl.class),
    B(BImpl.class),
    C(CImpl.class);

    private Class<? extends Intf> type;

    MyEnum(Class<? extends Intf> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public <T extends Intf> T getType() {
        try {
            return (T) type.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
A a = MyEnum.A.getType();
B b = MyEnum.B.getType();
C c = MyEnum.C.getType();
```

Comment: You got my vote for going forward and putting down an idea here!

Comment: @AxelH you're right, I missed that A,B,C are interfaces as well. Editing my answer to provide implementations if those interfaces, thanks for hinting this out.

Comment: But the compiler will not reject writing `A a = MyEnum.C.getType();` or `C c = MyEnum.A.getType();`. Things can get worse in generic code when that doesn’t even fail immediately at runtime, but lead to *heap pollution*, instances of wrong types stored somewhere, which will fail at an even later time, when no-one knows where the object came from. Think `<T extends Inf> Set<T> someMethod() { return Collections.<T>singleton(MyEnum.B.<T>getType()); }`…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are within class X, you have a local generic parameter, you could think of:

```
public <T extends Intf> T getType (MyEnum enumVal) {
  if (enumVal == MyEnum.A) {
    return (A) this;
  if (enumVal == MyEnum.B) {
    return (B) this;
```

But you don't gain anything from doing so. Those casts don't matter for the caller side.

Because there is nothing that the compiler could do for you here. You could write

```
A someA = whatever.getType(someEnum);
```

But you could as well write

```
B someB = whatever.getType(someEnum);
```

with the very same `someEnum`. And the compiler would be all happy.

If you want to achieve a gain on "compile time safety", you would have to somehow "connect" the argument type to the result type.

Comment: I want to use it on a builder with fluent api:  X.getType(MyEnum.A).a().build() or X.getType(MyEnum.B).b().build(), but never X.getType(MyEnum.A).b().build()

Comment: @marciel.deg That comment doesnt really clarify your requirements. As others said: please edit your question to be more specific then!

Comment: *Those casts don't matter for the caller side.* - you can wrap `this` into a new (anonymous inner class) instance of `A`, `B` or `C`, providing only access to `a()`, `b()` or `c()`.